# How to use Unicode character as Tkinter icon

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode

I am trying to use a Unicode character as `\uE8EF` as a Tkinter icon. Is it possible or should I just use an image instead?

I have tried (not my actual code):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap('\uE8EF')
#some buttons, widgets, a lot of stuff
```

How can I use a Unicode character as a Tkinter icon?

Comment: While this is certainly possible, it would be quite a lot of work - you'd need to use the PIL/Pillow module to create an image, draw your character into it, and then convert it into a form usable by Tkinter.  Much easier to just create an image in a paint program.

Comment: PIL has a module called ImageFont,you could draw it with your character and generate a image.